# When creating a function with summation in it, how do you add terms to the summation? (Python)

Tags: python, function, sum, iteration

I need to find a way to add new terms to the function:

f(x) = 4sin(x)/pi

such that the new function looks like this:

f(x) = 4sin(x)/pi + 4sin(3x)/3pi + 4sin(5x)/5pi + 4sin(7x)/7pi ... up to 201.

I was thinking I could create the function with a `for` loop inside that would iterate using a list `n` but there must be a way to do it. I am using the `math` and `numpy` libraries. This is what I have so far:

```
# original function f(x)
def f(x):
     return (4/math.pi)*math.sin(x)

# create list (n) composed of odd numbers up to 201 
n = list(range(1, 202, 2))

# new function with added terms
def newf(x):
     for i in n:
          sum (4/n[i]*math.pi)*math.sin(n[i]*x)
```

I am still relatively new to Python and cannot find a similar example to troubleshoot with. Am I thinking through this correctly? I'm unsure why this code would not work.

I do not know how to do math notation in Stack Overflow, so I apologize for that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to the solution! The reason is not working is because inside your loop nothing is retaining the computation of the previous iterations.
And you can simply use `i` without accessing `n[i]`, which eventually will throw you an `IndexError: list index out of range`

The code should provide you what you need:

```py
# original function f(x)
import math

def f(x):
     return (4/math.pi)*math.sin(x)

# create list (n) composed of odd numbers up to 201 
n = list(range(1, 202, 2))

def new_f(x):
    return sum([(4/i*math.pi)*math.sin(i*x) for i in n])
```

Comment: This worked! This is the answer I understand the logic of the most. I see now how I wasn't returning any actual answer, although I will need to keep learning how to use `for` loops in more "advanced" ways. Thank you datapug!

Comment: @Jay  Glad I could help! If this is the answer you were looking for, you can accept it (: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension like so:

```
def f(x):
    return sum([4 * math.sin(i * x) / (i * math.pi) for i in range(1,202,2)])
```

Comment: this is the most pythonic answer. It would be more readable with some line breaks though

Comment: So in this case `range(1,202,2)` is used instead of my list `n`, yes? Okay, I see how that would make it more compact. Thank you!

Comment: @Jay, yes that is the case. Furthermore, if you want `f` to be able to to handle a variable number of terms in your calculation you could do something like: `def f(x, n):` where `n` is the number at which the `range` stops and just change the call to `range` like this: `range(1, n + 1, 2)`. The `n + 1` is due to the fact that the stop condition, the number itself is not included into the range. You can also make the step size variable if you did something like this: `def f(x, n, step = 2):` where step will default to `2` if not provide to the `f` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in numpy. Create a function like this:

```
def func(x,i):
   return 4*np.sin(i*x)/(i*np.pi)
```

Then create a numpy array:

```
l = np.arange(1,202,2)
```

Then just apply for the disered x:

```
res = func(x,l).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the result o just the expression?
Here is a way to get the result:

```
import math

def f(x, i):
     value = 0.0
     for i in range(1, i*2+1, 2):
          value += (4/i*math.pi)*math.sin(x*i)
     return value

print(f(math.pi, 201))
```

With i you choose how many terms do you want

Comment: I am not sure what `value` means or is used for in this example. What does +- do for the function in this case?

Comment: value' stores the value of the result, it starts at 0 and with each cycle of the 'for' it adds each term, this is where += comes into play, it adds to the current value, instead of overwriting it. Is the same of doing value = value + (4/i*math.pi)*math.sin(x*i)